# Importing Binary Registry Key into VBScript

Tags: windows, vbscript, import, key, registry

i want to add the following registry key to the users pc via a login script. I've exported the key with the following content:

```
    [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\BrowserEmulation\ClearableListData]
"UserFilter"=hex:41,1f,00,00,53,08,ad,ba,03,00,00,00,86,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,\
  03,00,00,00,0c,00,00,00,51,4e,7c,4a,25,75,d1,01,01,00,00,00,0b,00,31,00,30,\
  00,2e,00,31,00,2e,00,31,00,30,00,30,00,2e,00,34,00,39,00,0c,00,00,00,0e,5c,\
  03,8c,b3,9b,d1,01,01,00,00,00,0c,00,70,00,72,00,69,00,6d,00,6f,00,74,00,65,\
  00,71,00,2e,00,63,00,6f,00,6d,00,0c,00,00,00,65,97,bf,e9,b3,9b,d1,01,01,00,\
  00,00,0b,00,31,00,30,00,2e,00,31,00,2e,00,31,00,30,00,30,00,2e,00,33,00,30,\
  00
```

How can i import this into a vbscript so users automatically gets these values into the registry?

Comment: Why a VBScript wouldn't `REG IMPORT "filename.reg"` be enough?

Comment: we have everything in a vbs login script, REG IMPORT is a option, but im currently looking for a way to do the thing into the same login script

Comment: You could just use [`Run()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx) of the `WScript.Shell` object to run the `REG IMPORT` command.

Comment: Since apparently you're in a domain: use GPP for this.

Comment: GPO: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc753092.aspx

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers pretty sure they said they have a vbs login script and want to add it to that. While GPO would be the better option, it doesn't help it they still want to use the VBScript method.

Comment: Thanks! already fixed with REG IMPORT